# Convergence of argmax of poisson point process under a continuous map

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This might just be a simple measure theory question, see the end remark, and apologies if that's the case.  Here's the setup:

Let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of Poisson point processes on a Euclidean space $S$ with $\sigma$-finite mean measure, and let $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function.

Suppose $\mu_n$ converge weakly to a PPP $\mu$.

The mapping theorem gives that the image of the point process $\mu = \sum \delta_x$ under $f$, which we denote $f^*\mu = \sum \delta_{f(x)}$, is a PPP on $\mathbb{R}$ as long as the induced measure $\mathbb{E} [\mu(f^{-1}(\cdot))]$ has no atoms.

My question is this.  Suppose further that $f < 0$ is continuous and negative, and we ask consider the $f$- maximizing point of $\mu_n$:

$$
\overline{x}_n = argmax_{x \in supp(\mu_n)} f(x).
$$

Does this converge in distribution to the $f$-maximizing point of $\mu$, $$
\overline{x} = argmax_{x \in supp(\mu)} f(x) ?
$$

I can show that $f^*\mu_n$ converges weakly to $f^*\mu$, and so it follows that the maximum of $f^*\mu_n$ converges in distribution to the maximum of $f^*\mu$.  The problem I'm having with showing the argmax is that for a Borel set $B \subset (-\infty,0)$,
$$
\{ \overline{x}_n \in f^{-1}(B)\} = \{\max f^*\mu_n \in B \},
$$
but need not $f^{-1}(B)$ generate the Borel sets in $S$, right?

Like I said above, sorry if this is just a simple measure theory question that didn't require any of the PPP stuff.